# Swift return index of array element

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to write function that walk through array and return indexes where that element was found.

Something like:

```
extension Array {

    func elementIndexes<T>() -> [Int] {

        // if element is kind of class "T" add it to array [T] and then return

    }
}
```

However, I have not succeeded. How can I do that?

Comment: So to be clear, you want to filter an array where you only get elements of type T?

Comment: if you want to get back indices, why is the return value `[T]`?

Comment: @holex sorry i misstype, i did edit. Of course, i want indexes.

Comment: @vadian i want to pass class type, and dont wan't to pass Any. i want to pass concrete type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds, to clear up the wording, that you want to get all indices where the element is type T. Here's an extension on Array that'll do that, with an example:

```
extension Array {

    func indices<T>(ofType type: T.Type) -> [Int] {
        return self.enumerated().filter({ $0.element is T }).map({ $0.offset })
    }

}

struct TypeA { }
struct TypeB { }

let list: [Any] = [TypeA(), TypeB(), TypeB(), TypeA()]

print(list.indices(ofType: TypeA.self)) // prints [0, 3]
```

Comment: @holex instead of that comment, you could have just pointed out my 1 typo

Comment: I have not debugged your code: just tested – then it failed.

Comment: Another alternative: `self.enumerated().flatMap{ $0.element is T ? $0.offset : nil }`

Answer (score 2):

You can filter the `indices` directly, this is *more generic* version (credits to `Leo Dabus` and `Hamish`)

```
extension Collection {

    func indices<T>(of type: T.Type) -> [Index] {
        return indices.filter { self[$0] is T }
    }
}
```

Comment: `indices.lazy.filter`

Answer (score 1):

this might work for you:

```
extension Array {

    func indices<T>(of: T.Type) -> [Int] {

        return self.enumerated().flatMap { $0.element is T ? $0.offset : nil }

    }

}
```

or if you'd like dealing with more traditional solutions then this is your way:

```
extension Array {

    func indices<T>(of: T.Type) -> [Int] {

        var indices = [Int]()

        for (n, item) in self.enumerated() {
            if item is T {
                indices.append(n)
            }
        }

        return indices
    }

}
```

---

like with this test array:

```
let array: [Any] = [1, 2, "3", "4"]

debugPrint(array.indices(of: String.self))
```

both presents the the same output in Playground, which is:

```
[2, 3]
```